# How to prevent double overflow in C?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, double, overflow

I'm looking for an answer to the question from the topic of this post. I don't have a problem when it comes to checking for integer overflow, but i don't know how to handle it with double variables. I would appreciate if anybody could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check it with a `long double`

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25294/Avoiding-Overflow-Underflow-and-Loss-of-Precision

Comment: @AlterMann: There's no guarantee that `long double` is longer than `double`.

Comment: You can use exactly the same method for floating point as for integer.

Comment: If `double` is an IEEE 754 format, and `long double` is at least the “extended” version of that format, then there is a guarantee that the product of two `double` values as `long double` is a finite `long double` value. But then again, if you know that the floating-point types map to IEEE 754 formats, why wouldn't you use the infinity values and overflow “exceptions” that were carefully designed for this purpose?

Comment: Not sure why code needs to prevent overflow, but if the operation was `c = a*b;`, could use `if (a >= MAX_DOUBLE/b) PreventOverflow(); else c = a*b;`.  (+/- and `b==0` features also needed) To best answer this post, OP needs to provide more details as to what higher level problem exists.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Because popular compilers were carefully designed to thwart that purpose? :)

Answer (score 1):

In IEEE-754, if the rounding mode is roundTiesToEven (the default) you can detect an overflow by checking an infinity result for normal operands as

> (IEEE-754:2008, 7.4 Overflow) "roundTiesToEven and roundTiesToAway carry all overflows to ∞ with the sign of the intermediate result"

Comment: Checking for infinity is independent of the rounding mode.  But it depends on how portable he wants to be; not all floating point formats have an infinity.

Comment: I mention the rounding mode, because in IEEE-754 not all rounding modes carry the overflows to infinity, e.g., roundTowardZero that carries to the format’s largest finite number. You also mention that not all floating points formats have an infinity but I'm addressing IEEE-754 where the three binary formats have the infinities.